# having more than one add child in one method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods

Why would this not work:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    int i;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        int r = arc4random_uniform(4);
        if (r == 0)
        {
            [self addChild: [self createBackground0]]; <- doesn't work
        }
        else if (r == 1)
        {
            [self addChild: [self createBackground1]]; <- doesn't work
        }
        else if (r == 2)
        {
            [self addChild: [self createBackground2]]; <- doesn't work
        }
        else
        {
            [self addChild: [self createBackground3]]; <- doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

where as this would:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    int i;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        [self addChild: [self createBackground0]]; <- works
    }
}
```

it seems as though that adding an addchild with a reference to the method, called createBackground0 as well as the other 1,2, and 3 works when i just have 1 by itself in that if statement that makes sure that the background can only spawn once. my original plan was to have a game where the player taps the screen to play the game but to make things a little less boring i made 4 different backgrounds where after i made an arc4random_uniform integer and assigned it to r then according to which number it picked in the if statement it would run that line of code and then send add a child respective to that. 
the createBackground method looks like this:

```
-(SKSpriteNode*) createBackground0
{
    SKSpriteNode *waves0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
    waves0.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-0.81,-0.5);
    waves0.name = @"waves0";

    return waves0;
}
```

i use an anchor point because .position isn't moving the sprite and I'm using .name because I'm going to reference the sprite in the update() method to make a scrolling background.

it seems to just work when i have one addchild but doesn't seems to be able to add two or three in the one method. does it have something to do with the amount of if statements.

sorry for any sloppy code as i am transitioning from c# to objective-c and only started about a week ago. thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` variable has not been initialized to `0`, which will lead to undefined behaviour (i.e. you cannot guarantee that `i == 0` in both cases).  Fix this with:

```
int i = 0;
```

The rest of your code looks like it should work fine.